Laravel Echo Auth Request Not Sending Cookie in Headers
My client side laravel-echo is not sending cookie param in headers, braodcasting/auth requires a cookie in headers to authorize websocket connection, when I try sending the same request with fetch it works but not when my laravel echo is involved, how can I send the cookie param in headers
I tried a few tricks but it did not work.
    window.Echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: 'reverb',
      wsHost: 'localhost',
      key: 'yn0yitpyoptuuqiyjrhm',
      wsPort: 8080,
      wssPort: 8080,
      forceTLS: false,
       authEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          Cookie: cookies,
        },
      withCredentials: true,
      enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    });


same problem here, any solutions !!

There might be any of the possible reason.Please check & configure the following.

make it sure that you have setup broadcasting configuration correctly in
*config/broadcasting.php* & *config/app.php*.
Ensure that broadcasting driver(i.e pusher,redis etc) are setup and properly
configured in *config/broadcasting.php* & .env file.
Ensure that routes/channel.php file contails the required channel routes
for the operation.

Try this and let me know...
window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'reverb',
  wsHost: 'localhost',
  key: 'yn0yitpyoptuuqiyjrhm',
  wsPort: 8080,
  wssPort: 8080,
  forceTLS: false,
  encrypted: true,
  auth: {
   headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Cookie: cookies,
    },
   endPoint : '/broadcasting/auth',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});


All of the above is working, I have tested the broadcast on Laravel, now I am trying to integrate it on reactjs but my echo is not sending cookie which laravel's broadcast/auth requires in order to authorize my connection, I am using Laravel reverb which was recently released

@ArmanAli - I have edited my post. Try the code.

This did not work as well because if I don't specify the full endpoint, it sends a request to react's port, my react is a separate application
